# scraping a search result

Tags: python, selenium

I want to scrape a search result dynamically.

How do I start scraping if I don't know the urls of the results of the searches?

This is not a single google search; it is search engine specific for finding results with the vin numbers of a car.

I have written the code that goes through an excel file and searches based on the vins. Search results come up one after each other in a new window, and I want to grab specific data from each result page.

I hope that makes sense.

Here is the code I have written so far in python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import openpyxl
import os
import webbrowser
import csv
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from openpyxl import load_workbook

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\siamak\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('VINS.xlsx')
sheet=wb['Sheet1']

for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=1, max_row=3):


    for cell in row:
        driver.get("http://www.autoreturn.com/las-vegas-nv/find-vehicle/")
        driver.find_element_by_name("vin")
        driver.find_element_by_name("vin").send_keys((cell.value).strip())
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="searchParameters"]/div[3]/div[2]""").click()
    #   driver.get("http://www.autoreturn.com/las-vegas-nv/find-vehicle/results")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="vehicle-search-results"]/form/div/input""").click()
        time.sleep(4)
```

Comment: Your code runs fine for me, where are you stuck? Does your code give you any errors you can share with us? Also, do you have an example of what `cell.value` may be to test with your code?

Comment: Obviously i am not asking the question correctly, yes the code runs and i get the search results, what i am asking is now i want to scrape the result of each query (3 in this case) in a nice format using urllib get and bs4, those are the ones i know, but i dont how to start the scraping (the search result url and it  changes as a new search is performed every 4 seconds with a new search result).  i am hoping that makes sense , it is harder to explain than to show what i like to do .  I appreciate any further thought after my explanation

Comment: It probably depends on what the search result looks like, but basically, you'd probably scrape the result like the example in the BeautifulSoup [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start), scrape the result of each query for the tags values you are wanting to save. maybe post an example query result ..

Comment: Thank you Jon for editing my question.

Comment: can you share what you are sending in sendKeys((cell.value).strip()) , I have tried manually but I do not have a VIN number so I couldn't proceed.

Comment: it is excel file with vin numbers in it , that is all , 3 vin numbers

Comment: 1GYEK13R7YR126485
1GCEK19V17E132248 
2G1WF5E36D1237118

Comment: 1GYEK13R7YR126485,
1GCEK19V17E132248 ,
2G1WF5E36D1237118,

Comment: cruuisepandey, here is the 3 vin numbers i am using

Comment: if you save those 3 vins in an excel file and call it VINS, then you can run the script and see exactly what i mean , I wanted to paste the excel file here myself , but i do not see the option to do that